# Archiving Build IOS Xcode - Stuck at running 2 of 4 custom shell scripts - React Native

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am creating the build for ios from Xcode (10.1) of React Native Project it always stuck on running 2 of 4 custom shell scripts.
[image]

node v8.12.0
npm 6.4.1
yarn 1.12.3
react-native-cli 2.0.1
watchman 4.9.0

Comment: don't worry it take time to fetch bundle

Comment: Archiving always takes some time, whether it is in native development or in react native development. It also depends on the size of your project. Big projects will take more time to archive.

Comment: i try to do waiting for 2 hours but it still stuck on this thing

Comment: Have you tried cleaning & archiving or deleting the derived data & then archiving. May be this would work for you.

Comment: yes many times but in vain

Comment: Try restarting your mac or xcode.

Comment: yes tried but nothing works